# Magento 2.0: Online Customer URL and IP Not showing

Tags: magento2

So I am having issues with locating .

**Where I can turn On the online customers IP and URL both are not showing on my platform.?**

I know on the last one I was able to fix it by going into the Logs and enabling it but seems this is more advanced.

Comment: are you still looking for an answer?

Comment: @AlexPaliarush if you have an answer, post it. people find this question via google and would be happy